# Finding duplicates and checking for overlapping periods

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-2016

I have a sheet with three columns as illustrated below

| Id | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20201101 | 20210131 |
| 2 | 20200801 | 20201031 |
| 2 | 20201101 | 99991231 |
| 3 | 20200901 | 99991231 |
| 3 | 20210301 | 99991231 |
| 4 | 20200301 | 20200930 |
| 4 | 20201001 | 20210430 |
| 4 | 20210315 | 99991231 |

I want to test if there are overlapping time ranges within each group of duplicate ids.
For example, the two rows with id = 3 have overlapping time ranges. The same goes for the last two rows of id = 4.

So I imagine that whenever the loop(?) finds an overlap, it throws me a msgbox with the corresponding id.

How can I achieve this?

I'm thinking that it might require a nested loop? And to test for overlap I would use the following logic:

```
If StartDate1 <= EndDate2 And StartDate2 <= EndDate1 Then ...
```

Comment: Rather than just having a loop to find common ID, and spitback a messagebox, i'd think to A) Sort by ID, B) find the range for your ID, and C) apply conditional formatting for the specific range, since you may have multiple in each group id.  There are many ways you can do this, so I feel like we would need more from you as to where you want to be, as this is currently a very open question, which doesn't quite fit StackOverflow.

Comment: Are the columns keeping Date formatted  `As Date`? I mean, are you sure about it? The format is not a standard one... I mean, what does `Debug.Print Year(StartDate1)` return in `Immediate Window`?

Answer (score 0):

You are rigth, a nested loop should do the job, and inside the loop you can test if the cells have the same ID

I think this code will solve your problem:

```
Sub overlap()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

last_line = ws.Range("a100000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To last_line
    StartDate1 = ws.Cells(i, 2)
    EndDate1 = ws.Cells(i, 3)
    ID1 = ws.Cells(i, 1)
    For j = i + 1 To last_line
        ID2 = ws.Cells(j, 1)
            If ID1 = ID2 Then
                StartDate2 = ws.Cells(j, 2)
                EndDate2 = ws.Cells(j, 3)
                If StartDate1 <= EndDate2 And StartDate2 <= EndDate1 Then
                    MsgBox "overlap at row: " & i & " (ID: " & ID1 & ")"
                End If
            End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```